# Can I add Silverlight 2.0 projects to my web app and still target .NET Framework 2.0?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, multi-targeting

Can I add new Silverlight 2.0 projects to my ASP.NET 2.0 web app and still target .NET Framework 2.0 in Visual Studio 2008?

ScottGu doesn't mention Silverlight [in his post on multi-targeting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx).

Michael Scwartz's posts on [Silverlight with Visual Studio .NET 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/06/04/silverlight-with-visual-studio-net-2005.aspx) and [How to create Silverlight Applications with Notepad](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/06/05/how-to-create-silverlight-applications-with-notepad.aspx) refer to VS2005 or to Silverlight 1.1 (i.e. pre-RTM).

Has anyone else tried this yet?

**[UPDATE]**

Now that I've upgraded the web project I started using the Silverlight control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael is right about using the object tag, but you'll also want to do two other things:

- Use a Post-Build step in the Silverlight project to copy the built xap file to your web project (as Silverlight links don't work with ASP.NET 2.0 projects).
- Add the Siverlight.js file to the object tag'd page to get better in-place installation and plugin detection.

Answer (score 2):

The targeting is a per project, there is no reason why you can't include multiple projects that target different frameworks in the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  Because Silverlight runs only on the client, you can invoke the Silverlight plug-in with an object tag:

```
<object width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
</object>
```